# I got trouble in using self-defining functions with Python

Tags: python, function

I wrote a simple program about User sign_up & log_in System with Python.I used many self-defining functions to make codes elegant. Here is the 'choose_page' function:

```
def choose_page():
    print('Welcome to the code system!')
    print('****************************\n')
    print('there are the three options:\n'
          '1.sign up\n'
          '2.log in\n'
          '3.quit')
    print('****************************\n')
    option = eval(input('Please input your option:'))
    return option
```

And here is 'sign_up' function:

```
def sign_up():
    global customer
    # global option
    # global option2
    ..................
    ..................(many codes)
    option2 = eval(input('Now you can log in the main page by inputting 2 or 0 to return the sign_page: '))
    return option2
```

I also wrote 'log_in' and 'quit' self-defining functions,then I can company them as I want like this(this step without 'quit' function as it doesn't matter now):

```
if choose_page() == 1:
    sign_up()     
    if sign_up() == 0:
        choose_page()
    elif sign_up() == 2:
        log_in()            
elif choose_page() == 2:
    log_in()
```

I run it but got trouble seems like logic error:

When I got in 'choose_page' and input 1,it run into 'sign_up',at the end of the 'sign_up',I input either 2 or 0 it still run into the 'sign_up' again and again without stopping.

Is there any logic error when I company these self-defining functions?
Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: Don't use `eval(input(...))`. If you are supposed to get an `int`, use `int(input(...))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you write `sign_up()` it's going to call it and run through the function. Python isn't smart. It doesn't go, "We've already run `sign_up()` before. I remember the answer. No need to run it again!" It does exactly what you tell it. If you write `sign_up()`, it calls `sign_up()`.

To avoid the repeated prompts you need to save its result to a variable and only call the function a single time.

```
if choose_page() == 1:
    sign_up_answer = sign_up()     
    if sign_up_answer == 0:
        choose_page()
    elif sign_up_answer == 2:
        log_in()
```

Repeat that same idea for any of the other functions that have the same problem.